How to cleanly mount a static filesystem with Angular and UberFx/Gin framework?
I am attempting to mount a static filesystem with the output of ng build and the Go Gin Framework. I have successfully mounted the filesystem from output of ng build; however, I have to make a GET call for every file that I wish to mount. I would like to know if there is a way to make fewer calls and/or include a whole directory with one call. Here is the output of ng-build:  and my code for mounting the filesystem (I am using the uberfx framework as well) . Any help would be appreciated.

That can be done much easier with the embed package and http.FS.
Basically, you have three steps:

Embed the files via the go:embed directive.
Strip the dist/client prefix from the client files.
Optionally add a different prefix path under which the files will be served.

package main

import (
    "embed"
    "flag"
    "io/fs"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

var (
    //go:embed dist/client
    content embed.FS

    bindAddress = flag.String("bind", ":48080", "The address to bind to.")
    pathPrefix  = flag.String("path", "/foo", "The path to serve the content.")
)

func main() {

    flag.Parse()

    var (
        router *gin.Engine = gin.Default()
        // A subset of our content.
        baseDir fs.FS
    )

    // We create a subset of our embedded content.
    // This way, we get rid of the "dist/client" prefix.
    baseDir, _ = fs.Sub(content, "dist/client")

    // Now, we can set any arbitary path to serve our content.
    router.StaticFS(*pathPrefix, http.FS(baseDir))

    router.Run(*bindAddress)
}

With the default settings shown above, the files dist/client/* will be available under http://0.0.0.0:48080/foo/<name of file>, with 0.0.0.0 meaning all local IPv4 addresses.
